# Roland Juno ds sound quality for recording

Tags: recording, keyboard, synthesizer, audio

I would like to ask what is the sample rate and bit resolution sound quality supported by the Roland Juno Ds61 keyboard?
Also I would like to know, what would be the difference if I use the midi cable to record audio directly or to record through an audio interface connected to the Juno Ds61?

The user "Your Uncle Bob" said once: "The Roland Juno-DS can send audio to your DAW over USB; this will give you better audio quality than connecting the Juno's audio outputs to an audio interface, because the audio isn't converted to analog and back to digital." Could anybody confirm this information, please?

Finally the only information I found on Roland Corporation Website is this: "The functionality and operation of the Juno-DS61/88 and your computer-based application(s) will be the same no matter which type of connection you are using - the only difference is how the MIDI and Audio signals are routed"

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

For the bit/sample rate, I am sure this kind of information can be found in the user manual, or maybe by asking Roland directly.

Uncle Bob is totally right saying that, if you can record using the USB of the Juno, meaning that it will, kind of, act as a sound card (it will seen as a sound card by the computer, but is not actually a sound card as no sound is actually produced and converted to digital) and send the digital audio directly to your computer, whereas, with a sound card plugged in the analog outputs, the synth is first converting digital to analog, and the sound card analog to digital again (if you could improve quality doing so, people would know it ;)).

Just one thing:

> if I use the midi cable to record audio directly

MIDI **cannot** carry audio signals. It can carry NoteOn/Off Messages, Control Change messages and a lot more but not audio. It is likely (but I did not check in the manual) that the Juno will be seen by the computer as an audio interface *and* a MIDI interface.

Comment: Thanks Tom. I understand that MIDI cannot carry audio signals. I was reffering to connecting the JUNO DS to the computer via USB cable (I can record audio and midi data by this way). The bit  rate info it is not in the manual but hopefully Roland send me the information

Comment: @SergioSlzr Point taken, that was a nitpick anyway ;). Did you solve your problem in the end?